# Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<int> in mvc controller

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

```
public ActionResult addstandardpackage1(ICollection<int> SingleStay,ICollection<int> DOUBLESTAY,ICollection<int> TRIBLESTAY,ICollection<int> FAMILYSTAY,ICollection<int> EXTRABED)
{
    var s = SingleStay;
    for (int i = 0; i < SingleStay.Count; i++ )
    {
        var cal = SingleStay[i];
    }
    foreach (var key in SingleStay)
    {
        var value = key;
    }          

}
```

In for Loop i am get the error like Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type But i need in for loop , in for each i am getting . because based on for loop i will bind the details with other collection lists. Please Help me.

I am getting error in `var cal=Singlestay[i]`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just convert it to an array:

```
var s = SingleStay.ToArray();
```

note that this will consume additional memory though.

Better way would be to get an Array or any other collection-form that supports indexer in the first place.

Yet another way would be to implement it with an index variable:

```
 var s = SingleStay;
 int i = 0;
 foreach (var cal in s)
 {
    //do your stuff (Note: if you use 'continue;' here increment i before)
    i++;
 }
```

Answer (score 37):

`ICollection` doesn't expose `indexer`. You have three options:

1. Change `ICollection` to `IList`
2. Use `ElementAt` that is inherited from `IEnumerable`. But be aware - it could not be efficient.
3. Evalute passed collection to list (`ToList()`)

[**ICollection**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx) (and its exposed methods) on msdn.

Comment: Thanks for ElementAt!

Comment: ElementAt is superb for debugging.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

or you can use

```
foreach (var item in Collection)
{
..................
}
```